# Good algorithm for searching DB for a given string

Tags: mysql, database, search, text

I'm working on a web app (PHP + MySQL) where a user can search for other users by inputting some search string.

I need to match the user's input string to 2 columns (username and fullName) of a 'User' table in my DB and return the most relevant (20 or 50) matches. Optimally, I also need to take into consideration misspellings.

How can I approach this? I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: take refrence from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: These days, people generally use technologies like Elastic Search and Apache Solr for things like this (you are already talking about search result relevance). I understand it is one more thing in your stack but it is less headache for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it using [MySQL full Text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html):

Please have look at [this](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/PHP-How-To-Sort-MYSQL-Fulltext-Search-By-Relevancy.html), [this](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/18), [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) articles.

I want to explain you about [Boolean Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html); But I advise you to please go through [Full Text Search using Query Expansion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html) also.

Let's look at the example table as given on dev.mysql.com:

```
mysql> select * from articles;
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title                 | body                                     |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial   | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  2 | How To Use MySQL Well | After you went through a ...             |
|  3 | Optimizing MySQL      | In this tutorial we will show ...        |
|  4 | 1001 MySQL Tricks     | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...      |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL     | In the following database comparison ... |
|  6 | MySQL Security        | When configured properly, MySQL ...      |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title             | body                                     |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+-------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order matters, when the words are quoted:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('"comparison database"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

When we remove the quotes, it will search for rows, containing words "database" or "comparison":

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('database comparison' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Order doesn't matter now:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('comparison database' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

If we want to get rows, containing either word "PostgreSQL" or phrase "database comparison", we should use this request:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('PostgreSQL "database comparison"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
| id | title               | body                                     |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PostgreSQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ...             |
|  5 | MySQL vs. YourSQL   | In the following database comparison ... |
+----+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

[Fiddle To Try](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72f54/1)

Make sure, that the words, you are searching for, are not in the [list of stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), that are ignored.
(and obviously words like 'is','the' are [stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and those are ignored)

**To enhance sorting of the results** in boolean mode you can use following queries:

(Assuming you have total 2 words in user's input string) Then.

```
SELECT column_names, MATCH (text) AGAINST ('word1 word2')
AS col1 FROM table1
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' in boolean mode) 
order by col1 desc;
```

(If you have 3 words in user's input string) Then..

```
SELECT column_names, MATCH (text) AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3')
AS col1 FROM table1
WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' in boolean mode) 
order by col1 desc;
```

Using the **first** `MATCH()` **we get the score in non-boolean search mode (more distinctive)**. The **second** `MATCH()` **ensures we really get back only the results we want (with all 3 words)**.

Answer (score -2):

i would do a like search whith two columns

My Query would be like this

select * from ( select * from user where (username  like ='%{input}%' or lastName like '%{input}%')) and rownum =20

You need to have a custom cleansing algorithm written to cleanse your input of misspellings

Comment: I need a much more sophisticated solution @Balaji

Comment: @Balaji, Joseph mentioned *most relevant matches*. This is only typical search